# How can i make my Discord bot mention a specific person in the channel?

Tags: python, bots, discord, discord.py

So i just recently started learning how to develop a Discord bot with Python and im pretty confused on how to make my bot mention people after a specific message is sent. What im trying to do is when i write "call George" in a specific channel, i want my bot to mention @George's_name and maybe something like "are you here?" after the mention.

From what i have seen, everyone says that in order to mention someone i need to copy his USER_ID and write something like <@USER_ID>, but i still dont know how the syntax is.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'Call George':
        await message.channel.send('Hey ', <@USER_ID> ,' are you here?')
```

As you can tell, whenever someone says "Call George", i want the bot to mention george and ask him if he is here. When i try to run my code though it tells me Invalid Syntax and highlights the <@USER_ID> part.

Comment: How are establishing the connection between the name George and the account you want to mention?  One you have the `Member` object representing that account, you can use `Member.mention` to mention that user.

Answer (score 1):

You have said in a comment that you have the id stored in a variable somewhere, you can use string.format(user_id) to ping the user
The reason it was giving an error is because you were using commas, Whilst this would work in print() you need to concatenate the string if you want to use send()
Hope this helped, Sorry for misinterpreting.

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'Call George':
        await message.channel.send('Hey ' + "<@{}>".format(userid) + ' are you here?')
```

if you have one person in mind and you want the function to only ping that person you can do this

```
async def on_message(self, message):
    if message.author == self.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'Call George':
        await message.channel.send('Hey ' + "<@123456>" + ' are you here?')
```

replace "123456" with their actual id.

Comment: Sorry my bad, i already know his USER_ID (lets say its 123456). The problem is that i dont know where to implement the <@123456> in the message.channel.send

Comment: @Nick is this better?

Comment: Do you mean you want to specifically ping this one person?

Comment: I've already tried that but there is an error telling me that "send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 4 were given"

Comment: Yes i want to ping one specific person.

Comment: Oh i just realised, send() doesnt work like print(). you need to concatenate and add spaces manually.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this syntax:

```
await message.channel.send("<@user_id>, are you here?")
```

where user_id is George's id. Example:

```
await message.channel.send("<@668503061970288660>, are you here?")
```